# How to call async function asynchronously without awaiting for the result

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

Let's say I have the following functions.

```
func first() async {
    print("first")
}

func second() {
   print("second")
}

func main() {
   Task {
      await first()
   }
   second()
}

main()
```

Even though marking `first` function as async does not make any sense as there is no async work it does, but still it is possible...

I was expecting that even though the first function is being awaited, it will be called asynchronously.

But actually the output is

```
first 
second
```

How would I call the fist function asynchronously mimicking the GCD's variant of:

```
DispatchQueue.current.async { first() }
second()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior will change depending upon the context.

- If you invoke this from a non-isolated context, then `first` and `second` will run on separate threads. In this scenario, the `second` task is not actually waiting for the `first` task, but rather there is a race as to which will finish first. This can be illustrated if you do something time-consuming in the `first` task and you will see the `second` task is not waiting at all.

  This introduces a race between `first` and `second` and you have no assurances as which order they will run. (In my tests, it runs `second` before `first` most of the time, but it can still occasionally run `first` before `second`.)
- However, if you invoke this from an actor-isolated context, then `first` *will* wait for `second` to yield before running.

So, the question is, do you really care which order these two tasks start? If so, you can eliminate the race by (obviously) putting the `Task { await first() }` after the call to `second`. Or do you simply want to ensure that `second` won’t wait for `first` to finish? In that case, this already is the behavior and no change to your code is required.

---

You asked:

> What if `await first()` needs to be run on the same queue as `second()` but asynchronously. … I am just thinking [that if it runs on background thread that it] would mean crashes due to updates of UI not from the main thread.

You can mark the routine to update the UI with [`@MainActor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/), which will cause it to run on the main thread. But note, do not use this qualifier with the time-consuming task, itself (because you do not want to block the main thread), but rather decouple the time-consuming operation from the UI update, and just mark the latter as `@MainActor`.

E.g., here is an example that manually calculates π asynchronously, and updates the UI when it is done:

```swift
func startCalculation() {
    Task {
        let pi = await calculatePi()
        updateWithResults(pi)
    }
    updateThatCalculationIsUnderway() // this really should go before the Task to eliminate any races, but just to illustrate that this second routine really does not wait
}

// deliberately inefficient calculation of pi

func calculatePi() async -> Double {
    await Task.detached {
        var value: Double = 0
        var denominator: Double = 1
        var sign: Double = 1
        var increment: Double = 0

        repeat {
            increment = 4 / denominator
            value += sign * 4 / denominator
            denominator += 2
            sign *= -1
        } while increment > 0.000000001

        return value
    }.value
}

func updateThatCalculationIsUnderway() {
    statusLabel.text = "Calculating π"
}

@MainActor
func updateWithResults(_ value: Double) {
    statusLabel.text = "Done"
    resultLabel.text = formatter.string(for: value)
}
```

Note: To ensure this slow synchronous calculation of `calculatePi` is not run on the current actor (presumably the main actor), we want an “unstructured task”. Specifically, we want a “detached task”, i.e., one that is not run on the current actor. As the *Unstructured Concurrency* section of [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency: Tasks and Task Groups](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642) says:

> To create an unstructured task that runs on the current actor, call the [`Task.init(priority:operation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856790-init) initializer. To create an unstructured task that’s not part of the current actor, known more specifically as a detached task, call the [`Task.detached(priority:operation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856786-detached) class method.

Comment: You are right, I added 1 second delay to `first` function before `print("first")` and `first` was logged after `second` in console. What if `await first()` needs  to be run on the same queue as `second()` but asynchronously, is that possible with the `Task` api, or GCD would be needed to achieve that?

Comment: I am just thinking if `Task { ... }` is more to `DispatchQueue.global().async { first() }` than for the UI code that would mean crashes due to updates of UI not from the main thread.

Comment: Answering my own comment, adding `@MainActor` attribute to the `first()` function makes sure that it will be scheduled on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, but be careful. Decouple time-consuming stuff from the UI update. The UI update function would bear `@MainActor` qualifier, but the time-consuming function, `first`, should not.

Comment: @VladislavBrylinskiy What are you trying to achieve by running `first()` and `second()` on the same queue? Does putting them inside an actor solve your problem?